# Can't boot Angular app after compiling to single file

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs, gulp-typescript

I'm having trouble booting my app after upgrading to TypeScript 1.8 and compiling my app to a single file with `outFile`.

All my files are compiled to a single `app.js` in the dist folder of my project. I can see in the network inspector that `app.js` is correctly loaded from the server. No errors are shown but it seems like my `bootstrap` function for app is never executed. The app works fine when not compiled.

***SystemJS setup***

```
System.config({
  map: {
    'app': '/path/to/dist'
  },
  packages: {        
    '/path/to/dist': {
      main: 'app',
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
System.import('app')
  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

***boot.ts***

```
// Required for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7052
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/> 
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ComponentRef, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppComponent} from './components/app/app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
import {PanelsService} from './components/panels/panels.service';
import {StoriesService} from './components/stories/stories.service';
import {UrlService} from './components/common/url.service';
import {UserService} from './components/user/user.service';
import {AppService} from './components/app/app.service';
import {AlertsService} from './components/alerts/alerts.service';

.................
.................
.................
.................

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
  PanelsService,
  .............
  .............
  .............
  AlertsService
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I'm sure I'm missing something straightforward here. Do I need to NOT include my `boot.ts` in my concatenated file?

For the sake of completeness, I'm using `gulp-typescript 2.12.0` to compile my source files using the following task....

```
return gulp
  .src('app/**/*.ts')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

...and my `tsconfig.json` is the following

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outFile": "app.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have all your compiled JS code into your single file. So you need to include this JS file in a `script` tag and to update your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script src="/path/to/dist/app.js"></script
<script>
  System.config({
  });
  System.import('app')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I was under the false impression that importing `app.js` would boot the application.

Comment: You're welcome! ;-) In fact, not. It "only" provides all the modules of your application within a single file. You still need to bootstrap your application but importing the "entry point" module. Otherwise the `bootstrap` function is never called...